Produce multiple-page website on shinyapps.io from long RMarkdown file containing text and shiny apps
I have an RMarkdown file that contains lots of text and also several chunks for scraping and cleaning data and shiny apps - it looks like this published: https://plotsrdata.shinyapps.io/stackoverflow/, i.e. just one long page of text and interactive plots.
I want to separate it into three pages: Overview (just text), Findings (text and data/app chunks), Conclusion (text and image). I thought I could split the .Rmd file up into three .Rmds corresponding to each section, then use navbarPage to put them all together. I naively thought this would be straightforward but after hours of trying I'm still just getting three blank pages with a weird semi border (that I don't want):

I tried this but anything outside just one plain markdown file with text and chunks is new to me so I'm not sure if any of it is any use or whether I should be doing something entirely different:
    library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Research",
             tabPanel("Overview",
                      uiOutput("overviewContent")),
             tabPanel("Findings",
                      uiOutput("findingsContent")), # Dynamic UI for findings
             tabPanel("Conclusions",
                      uiOutput("conclusionsContent"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$overviewContent <- renderUI({
  
    output_html <- rmarkdown::render('overview.Rmd', envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    tags$iframe(style="width:100%; height:600px;", src=output_html)
  })
  
  output$findingsContent <- renderUI({
    output_html <- rmarkdown::render('findings.Rmd', envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    tags$iframe(style="width:100%; height:600px;", src=output_html)
  })
  
  output$conclusionsContent <- renderUI({
    output_html <- rmarkdown::render('conclusions.Rmd', envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    tags$iframe(style="width:100%; height:600px;", src=output_html)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

